# searching course and country without cities

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Thanks to all...
One more question is there..
i have query its searching without city, am selecting course and country its displaying the particular course having particular country and all the cities of that country, its working fine. But problem is when am entering same course for same city twice and searching its displaying one query is fine another query its displaying the name of last city in that particular country and id of that city what is the issue.in wordpress.
my code is:

```
if($the_query->post_count > 0)
            {
                echo "post count".$the_query->post_count; echo "<br />";
                //echo "the query <br/>";


                for($i=0; $i < $the_query->post_count; $i++){ 

                $sql_city = "select name ,term_id from wp_terms where term_id = $x[$i]"; echo "<br />";
                echo $sql_city;
                $query_city = mysql_query($sql_city);
                if($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_city))
                 {
                    $term_id = $row['term_id'];
                    $name = $row['name'];
                 }  
                 echo $term_id;echo "<br />";
                 echo $name;

            ?>

             <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $the_query->posts[$i]->post_title; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo strtoupper ($_SESSION['header_country']);  ?></td>
                    <td><?php if(empty($_POST['city']))
                    {echo strtoupper ($name);}
                    else
                    { echo strtoupper($_POST['city']);
                    } ?></td>
                    <?php /*?><td><?php echo strtoupper ($_POST['city']); ?></td><?php */?>
                    <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo $home_url."/course/".$the_query->posts[$i]->post_name; ?>">Know More</a>
            <a class="btn btn-warning"  href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/shop/?add-to-cart=<?php echo $the_query->posts[$i]->ID; ?>">Enroll Now</a>
                   </td>
              </tr>
            <?php 
            } 
            }
```

Comment: i know the problem of above query can you please just share your thoughts how am able to solve this.The problem is we passing query_count($the_query->post_count) i.e product count. but we are fetching the city list.i think that problem of this below code only.

Comment: $sql_cities = "SELECT term_id  FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE parent ='$term_id'";
echo $sql_cities;
$query_cities = mysql_query($sql_cities);
$city_id_list="";
$x = array();
$ctr = mysql_num_rows($query_cities);
echo "the count".$ctr;echo "<br />";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_cities))
{
  $term_id = $row['term_id'];
  $x[] = $row['term_id'];
 if($ctr == 1)
  {
   $city_id_list = $city_id_list.$term_id;
  }
  else
  {
   $city_id_list = $city_id_list.$term_id.',  ';
  }
$ctr = $ctr - 1;
echo $city_id_list."===ctr=".$ctr;echo "<br />";
}

Comment: if($the_query->post_count > 0)
    {
     echo "post count".$the_query->post_count; echo "<br />";
     for($i=0; $i < $the_query->post_count; $i++){ 
    $sql_city = "select name ,term_id from wp_terms where term_id = $x[$i]"; echo "<br />";
    echo $sql_city;
    $query_city = mysql_query($sql_city);
     if($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_city))
     {
      $term_id = $row['term_id'];
      $name = $row['name'];
      }